# How to display the exact search keyword in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am using regex for searching the directory for a list of keywords. Here is my current code:

```
   if (/$search/i) 
   {

        printf $out "%s\t%s\n",$File::Find::name,$1;       
   }
```

In my above code `$1` is giving only the keyword phrase.
But I want the entire keyword.

example: I am searching "sweep"

current output: `C:\ac\acfrd\file.sql SWEEP`. 
But the file contains the word "SWEEP_ID", and I want the output to be "SWEEP_ID", not "SWEEP".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/\b(\w*$search\w*)\b/i
```

It captures your search term and optional adjacent *word-symbols* (`\w` - letters, digits, etc.) into `$1`. The captured character sequence is surrounded by *word-boundaries* (`\b` - punctuation, whitespace, string beginning or ending).

The regex above allows additional word-symbols both before and after your search term. If you only want to allow additional symbols *after* your search term (as in your example), just remove the first `\w*`:

```
/\b($search\w*)\b/i
```

If you do not want to rely on Perl's definition of "word symbols", then replace `\w` with your own character class, e.g. (only allow letters and underscores):

```
/\b([_a-z]*$search[_a-z]*)\b/i
```

Comment: If you move away from `\w`, you need to move away from `\b` too. That last one should be: `/(?<![_a-z])([_a-z]*$search[_a-z]*)(?![_a-z])/i` (or rather `/(?<![_\pL])([_\pL]*$search[_\pL]*)(?![_\pL])/i`)

Comment: @ikegami: I didn't want to go too deep and explain lookahead/lookbehind, but actually you are right... Thanks for pointing this out. +1 to your comment.

Comment: @AlexShesterov : It is working Thanks for your help . I  am begineer in perl can you help me out in finding any Website where can i learn about perl in more detail.

Comment: @Ramesh: of course, with pleasure. Perl Q+A site (like SO, but Perl-specific): http://perlmonks.org/ ; Tutorials, full docs, etc. on official site: http://learn.perl.org/ ; CPAN - Perl's collection of ready-to-use modules: http://search.cpan.org/.

Comment: @Ramesh: CPAN is actually the Perl's greatest strength: it contains out-of-the-box solutions to many problems - from different ways of XML parsing to controlling MS Office application, interface to Subversion and different databases, etc. *When programming in Perl, you should think of CPAN all the time.* If you are about to implement a kind of general-purpose module which you need in your business application (like a module of sending mails via MS Outlook) - try searching CPAN first, the chances are that what you need is already there, and you can concentrate on your specific business problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
/($search\S+)/
```

This might work but your question isn't clear...